# Setting up the navigation bar as transparent and dimmed at the same time

Tags: android, android-theme, android-4.4-kitkat

There are some Android 4.4 applications in which the system's navigation bar is simultaneously dimmed and transparent. One example of this is the camera app on the Xperia Z1:

[image: f]

I've been trying to find a way to replicate this, and so far I have no problem setting up the navigation bar as translucent (by setting the style to `android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor`, for instance) or as dimmed:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE | decorView.getSystemUiVisibility();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

The thing is, I can't seem to find a way to do *both* of them at the same time (i.e. simultaneously dimmed *and* transparent). It seems that whenever I define the app's style to use the transparent navigation bar, the dim flag stops having any effect.

I've tried a lot of different stuff with no results... Any suggestion? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Not yet... (kind of left this problem to be solved later on)

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: Not yet. If I find a solution I promise I'll post it here.